# How to handle 2 OUT user-defined custom data types from Java Spring Data JPA @NamedStoredProcedureQuery defined on @Entity class?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

**UPDATE:**
I have tried implementing the `SQLData` interface for my `Financial.class` and `PersonalInfo.class` Java POJOs defined on my `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` for the type. I also implemented the required `getSQLTypeName`, `readSQL`, and `writeSQL` methods per an Oracle doc:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/samapp6.htm

I was hoping this would work, but it looks like its still giving me the same `Type cannot be null` exception. Does it matter that these `personal_information_t` and `financial_t` Objects defined in my Oracle DB are inheriting from a superclass, called `base_t` ?

---

Hi guys, I'm simply trying to use the `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` directly on my `@Entity` class to call a Stored Procedure that is in my Oracle Database (that is in a separate schema, `"JJR"`). I can indeed correctly connect to this database programmatically from my Java Spring Boot application, and I can run JPA queries successfully like `.findAll()` so I know its not a connection issue but I believe something to do with my @NamedStoredProcedure declaration. All the tutorials on Google for Spring JPA Stored Procedure queries are using standard data types like Long or String, and only returning **one** OUT parameter.

However, I'm returning two OUT parameters and to make it more complicated, they are user-defined types (defined in the Oracle Database), so I'm trying to figure out how to handle this as my current attempt is returning back this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Type cannot be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
```

My Stored Procedure structure (It is inside a Package in my oracle db of `pkg_employee_data` in schema/user `JJR`). The user-defined types (`personal_information_t` and `financial_t` both have multiple fields in them, i.e. personal_information_t has an userid, firstname, lastname, and financial_t has salary, networth etc..:

```
PROCEDURE get_employee_data (
            empid      IN       emp.emp_id%TYPE, // NUMBER(38,0)
            persinfo   OUT      personal_information_t, // user-defined type
            financ     OUT      financial_t / user-defined type

   );
```

And how I'm defining the `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery`

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Employee.getEmployeeData",
        procedureName = "pkg_employee_data.get_employee_data", parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "empid", type = Long.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "persinfo", type = PersonalInfo.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "financ", type = Financial.class)})
public class Employee {

    // Should I list the columns I want mapped here in the Entity 
    // from the "persinfo" and "financ" user-defined types, that 
    // should have a bunch fields/data inside them?
    @Id
    private long userId;
    private String firstName;
    private Double salary;

}
```

And the `@Repository` declaration, where I map this method:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee,Long> {

    @Procedure(name = "Employee.getEmployeeData")
    Map<String, Object> getEmployee(@Param("empid") long empid);
}
```

1. Are my `type = "*.class"` declarations even correct on the `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` annotation? seems like my Types ares getting read a null. I created a `PersonalInfo.java` and `Financial.java` `@Entities` in my code as I hoped it would map from the Oracle user-defined types but it doesn't seem like that's working.
2. On all my `@Entities`, I have to declare some meta-information like `@Table(schema = "JJR", name = "MY_TABLE_NAME")` because as I stated above, I'm logging into a specific user/schema in my Oracle DB. Do I need to put this on the @NamedStoredProcedureQuery too? I'm not mapping to a table here technically though (I just need the data from the two OUT parameters).
3. I even tried using `java.sql.Struct.class` as the Type in the `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` per Google, but nothing seems like it's working.
4. What actually columns/fields do I need defined in the `Employee` Entity, which has the `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` annotation on it? I'm not really mapping to a Table, like normally we use @Entity. This stored procedure is just returning those two OUT parameters (`personal_information_t` and `financial_t` and I need the data from it). Should the fields in Employee class be simply the fields that are in the Oracle user-defined types that I need?

Comment: Hi, did you make any progress with this?

Comment: Hi, Please any luck working with this, @bloodopal were you able to find anything